# Non-deterministic Pushdown Automaton to Context-Free Grammar

Tags: context-free, pushdown-automata, nondeterminism

While doing the exercise about questions about transforming NPDA to CFG, I encountered the following question:

Find a CFG for the following NPDA $M = (\{q_0, q_1\}, \{a, b\}, \{A, z\}, \delta, q_0, z, \{q_1\})$, with transitions:
$$
\begin{align}
\delta(q_0, a, z) &= \{(q_0, Az)\} \\
\delta(q_0, b, A) &= \{(q_0, AA)\} \\
\delta(q_0, a, A) &= \{(q_1, \lambda)\}
\end{align}
$$

Since all the transitions are in the form $\delta(q_i, a, A) = \{c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n\}$ where $c_i = (q_j, \lambda)\mid(q_j, BC)$, I tried the procedure taught in the book I was reading:

- For the transition reducing the height of the stack, we get
  $$
  (q_0Aq_1) \rightarrow a
  $$
- Then for the other two transitions, we get
  $$
  \begin{align}
  (q_0zq_0) &\rightarrow a(q_0Aq_0)(q_0zq_0) \mid a(q_0Aq_1)(q_1zq_0) \\[1ex]
  (q_0zq_1) &\rightarrow a(q_0Aq_0)(q_0zq_1) \mid a(q_0Aq_1)(q_1zq_1) \\[1ex]
  (q_0Aq_0) &\rightarrow b(q_0Aq_0)(q_0Aq_0) \mid b(q_0Aq_1)(q_1Aq_0) \\[1ex]
  (q_0Aq_1) &\rightarrow b(q_0Aq_0)(q_0Aq_1) \mid b(q_0Aq_1)(q_1Aq_1)
  \end{align}
  $$

Since there are no productions of $q_1\alpha q_k$ at the left size, we eliminate every productions with them, resulting in
$$
\begin{align}
(q_0zq_0) &\rightarrow a(q_0Aq_0)(q_0zq_0) \\[1ex]
(q_0zq_1) &\rightarrow a(q_0Aq_0)(q_0zq_1) \\[1ex]
(q_0Aq_0) &\rightarrow b(q_0Aq_0)(q_0Aq_0) \\[1ex]
(q_0Aq_1) &\rightarrow b(q_0Aq_0)(q_0Aq_1) 
\end{align}
$$
And the starting symbol being $(q_0zq_1)$.

But from here, if we replace $(q_0zq_1)$ with $S$, $(q_0Aq_0)$ with $A$, $(q_0zq_0)$ with $B$ and $(q_0Aq_1)$ with $C$,
its easy to spot that it never terminates:
$$
\begin{align}
B &\rightarrow aAB \\[1ex]
S &\rightarrow aAS \\[1ex]
A &\rightarrow bAA \\[1ex]
C &\rightarrow a\mid bAC 
\end{align}
$$

So the questuion is: **What am  I doing wrong?**
(If this does help —
From the Peter Linz book, 6th-edition, Section 7.2 Exercise 16.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to be doing right. The original PDA can only push symbols except it can pop one $A$ while moving to state $q_1$. Probably a typo. I cannot find errata.

Comment: @HendrikJan working on finding them. Thanks for the edit btw.